# Invoice Number Generation

Tags: ms-access

I started a small business and have created an accounting DB with advice from my accountant.

In Part of my business I generate invoices for the same customers every month. I use a unique invoice number that helps with tracking etc.

So I haven't been able to get an auto number to work. Currently, I dump the records in monthly then manually update the invoice number, but it is taking too much time now. I have been trying to adapt some code I found online but I am new to the coding end of Access. Most of the time I have been able to get things done with queries and macros.

So this is the code that I am trying to adapt.

```
Private Sub InvUDB_Click()
Dim InvNo As DAO.Database
Dim rstMInvoice As DAO.Recordset
Dim rstInv1 As DAO.Recordset
   Set InvNo = CurrentDb
   Set rstMInvoice = InvNo.OpenRecordset("MInvoice")   '**** This is the line that the debugger opens up to after the error
   Set rstInv1 = InvNo.OpenRecordset("Inv1")

   rstMInvoice.MoveFirst
   Do Until rstInvoice.EOF
      If rstMInvoice!Invoice = 0 Then

         rstMInvoice.Edit
         rstMInvoice!Invoice = rstInv1!Inv
         rstMInvoice.Update

      End If
      rstMInvoice.MoveNext

      DoCmd.SetWarnings False
         DoCmd.OpenQuery "Invoice_Q000"
         DoCmd.OpenQuery "Invoice_Q002"
         DoCmd.SetWarnings True
   Loop
End Sub
```

I get an error message 3167:

> “You referred to a record that you deleted or that another user in a multiuser environment deleted. Move to another record, and then try the operation again.”

When I Debug it highlights The following row:

> Set rstMInvoice = InvNo.OpenRecordset("MInvoice")

I use the two queries below this line to generate a temp table with the new invoice number, (Max Inv No for current year and Month Plus 1).

I have tried running these queries in different places in the code with no luck.

As you can see I do not have a clue as how to write this or how to get this code to run. When I replace everything past the equal sign with a constant it works but it replaces all the qualifying records with that constant.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub InvUDB_Click()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rstMInvoice As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rstInv1 As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim newInvoice As Long
    
    ' Set the current database
    Set db = CurrentDb
    
    ' Open recordsets for MInvoice and Inv1 tables
    Set rstMInvoice = db.OpenRecordset("MInvoice")
    Set rstInv1 = db.OpenRecordset("Inv1")
    
    rstMInvoice.MoveFirst
    Do Until rstMInvoice.EOF
        If IsNull(rstMInvoice!Invoice) Or rstMInvoice!Invoice = 0 Then
            ' Generate a new invoice number using the query
            strSQL = "SELECT Max(Inv) + 1 AS NewInvoice FROM Inv1"
            newInvoice = Nz(DLookup("NewInvoice", strSQL), 1)
            
            ' Update the Invoice field with the new invoice number
            rstMInvoice.Edit
            rstMInvoice!Invoice = newInvoice
            rstMInvoice.Update
        End If
        
        rstMInvoice.MoveNext
    Loop
    
    rstMInvoice.Close
    rstInv1.Close
    Set rstMInvoice = Nothing
    Set rstInv1 = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    
    ' Run the queries
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Invoice_Q000"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Invoice_Q002"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

added a check to see if the Invoice field in the MInvoice table is Null or 0, and if so, it will generate a new invoice number and update the field with the new value.